# Big difference in timestamps when running same application multiple times on an emulator

Tags: java, android, android-emulator

In an android application I am trying to do a exponential modulus operation and want to calculate the time taken for that process. So i have created 2 timestamps,one just before the operation and the other just after the operation

```
Calendar calendar0 = Calendar.getInstance();
java.util.Date now0 = calendar0.getTime();
java.sql.Timestamp currentTimestamp0 = new java.sql.Timestamp(now0.getTime());

BigInteger en = big.modPow(e, n);

Calendar calendar1 = Calendar.getInstance();
java.util.Date now1 = calendar1.getTime();
java.sql.Timestamp currentTimestamp1 = new java.sql.Timestamp(now1.getTime());
```

The difference in time reported by these 2 timestamps is varying over a large range for the same inputs when i am running application multiple times. It gives time in range of [200ns-6ns]

Can someone point out the reason for such result/something that i am doing wrong?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out, i didn't know about that n here's your upvote!

Answer (score 3):

Well for one thing, you're going about your timing in a very convoluted way. Here's something which gives just as much accuracy, but rather simpler:

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
BigInteger en = big.modPow(e, n);
long end = System.currentTimeMillis();
```

Note that `java.util.Date` only has accuracy to the nearest millisecond, and using that same value and putting it in a `java.sql.Timestamp` doesn't magically make it more accurate. So *any* result under a millisecond (6ns-200ns) is obviously spurious - basically anything under a millisecond is 0.

You *may* be able to get a more accurate reading using `System.nanoTime` - I don't know whether that's supported on Android. There may be alternative high-precision timers available, too.

Now as for why operations may actually take very different amounts of recorded time:

- The granularity of the system clock used above may well be considerably less than 1ms. For example, if it measures nothing smaller than 15ms, you could see some operations supposedly taking 0ms and some taking 15ms, even though they *actually* take the same amount of time.
- There can easily be other factors involved, the most obvious being garbage collection

Comment: I would even say this code _gives_ accuracy while the code in the question do not.

Comment: Thanks for tiding things up. I tried System.nanoTime() works in android, but the fluctuation in reported times still exist. Do you know of a better way to report time taken by a particular process in software. I will basically be using this data to compare it time taken for same process(exponential modulus operation ) in hardware/.

Comment: @JoshMachine: It's better to measure how long it takes to perform the same operation many, many times - so that you don't need to worry about the inaccuracy of measuring very small times.

Comment: trythe debug class android ha a profiler that you can use to start profiling and stop it (from GUI as well, if you se eclipse) so you can get profiler time on it, as for why it happens, well you are right 180 milli is a big difference, do you happen toknow what other proceses are running on your PC and emulator, they may affect...

Answer (score 1):

Do more calculations in the trial so that your expected time is several milliseconds.

Consider doing your output to logcat, recording that on the PC and then processing the logcat to only select trials with no intervening platform messages about garbage collection or routine background operations.

Answer (score 1):

A large part of the reason for the variation is that your application is being run by a virtual machine running under a general-purpose operating system on an emulated computer which is running under a general-purpose operating system on a real computer.

With the exception of your application, every one of the things in that pile (the JVM running your app, Android's Linux OS, the emulator and whatever OS runs it) may use the CPU (real or virtual) to do something else at any time for any duration.  Those cycles will take away from your program's execution and add to its wall-clock execution time.  The result is completely nondeterministic behavior.

If you count emulator CPU cycles consumed and discount whatever Java does behind the scenes, I have no doubt that the standard deviation in execution times would be a lot lower than what you're seeing for the same inputs.  The emulated Android environment isn't the place to be benchmarking algorithms because there are too many variables you can't control.

Answer (score 0):

You can't make any conclusions only running a single function. There's so much more going on. You have no control over the underlying linux operating system taking up cycles, let alone the java virtual machine, and yet still all the other programs running. Try running it 1000 or 10000 times